# Git : few exes not properly checkout

Tags: git, windows-10, git-extensions, python-exec

Am using git version 2.21.0.windows.1 with Git Extensions v 2.48.05 on Windows 10.

In our project there are few python executable. After I clone our repository, there are many exe which are not getting checked-out properly. I separately copied the python executable folder from other system and replaced it in my system, then noticed that there are changes in these executable.
[image]

Any suggestion to fix this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try again cloning, after a:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

That will ensure no end-of-line conversion is done, which can sometime mess up binaries.
A [`.gitattributes` with `eol=lf` or `crlf` directives](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_checking_out_and_checking_in) is more precise and won't touch *all* the files.

(On the other hands, binaries should not be versioned in a source control like Git, but fetched from a artifact referential like Nexus or Artifactory)